# What tree is this which is 12 ft tall and 15ft wide with tiny black fruit

Tags: identification, trees, diagnosis

This grows in my backyard and its leaning on the divider and would like to know few more details about it before trimming it. For that if like to know what tree is this first..

[image: The full tree]

--

[image: Close up of a small trunk with the black fruit]

--

[image: Single branch]

--

[image: Trunk of the tree]

--

[image: Fruit]

--

[image: Smashed]

--
[image: Seed]

Comment: Its living in northern California, zone 9b

Comment: Do you remember any flowers?

Comment: Been seeing this since October 15 and no flowers on it, thanks a lot for trying so hard  don't think they have opposite, I see mostly alternate..

Comment: To be able to produce those black berries there HAS to be flowers.  All plants flower some are more visible than others.  Do you see any buds, vegetative or otherwise?  That would help greatly even without the flowers.  I am surprised that others haven't jumped on this question!  They will...there are some incredible IDer's on here; look for Bamboo, Kevinsky, Steph...my goodness.  Whatever tree it is, cutting out superfluous branches that aren't producing (small tiny caliper branches...cut at main stem with sterilized bypass pruners)...any branches growing toward the center.

Answer (score 4):

Sigh, my first impression was Crepe Myrtle.  Your pictures don't show the leaf arrangement very well but they should be OPPOSITE.  There will sometimes be weird alternate looking leaves.  You SHOULD be able to remember the flowers, if indeed this is Crepe Myrtle.  If it is you are one lucky person!  These trees in the correct location like where you are...are one of the most beautiful and hugely flowering SMALL trees ever. If you lived there last year and do not remember a huge flower display then perhaps not.  Of course if they were fertilized with too much nitrogen the flowers would have been miniscule.  More pictures!  This looks like a very wonderful small tree and should be thinned to show the trunks/branching...and help with formation, health.  MORE PICTURES!  Regardless, this is a great little tree and will be a boon to your landscape when you know what it is and how to prune it...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Grumichama
I have one and the fruits are nice when ripe.
The fruits get bigger as the tree matures:
https://www.daleysfruit.com.au/fruit%20pages/grumichama.htm